# Error while writing Spark DataFrame to csv in pyspark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to apply ALS matrix factorization provided in the MLlib. Below is my code

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

t1 =         
sqlContext.read.csv("/user/hadoop/personalization/test1.csv",header=False)

from pyspark.mllib.recommendation\
import ALS,MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating

model=ALS.train(t1,rank=2,iterations=20,seed=0)

products_for_users = model.recommendProductsForUsers(2).collect()


l2=sqlContext.createDataFrame(products_for_users)
l2.show()
l2.write.csv('l2.csv')
```

At the last step, after executing the write.csv(), I am getting the following error: Can Someone please identify the source of the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 674, in csv
    self._jwrite.csv(path)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", 
lin                                                                                        
e 933, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", 
line 31                                                                                        
2, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o140.csv.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support struct<_1:struct<user:bigint,product:bigint,rating:double>,_2:struct<user:bigint,pro                                                                                        duct:bigint,rating:double>> data type.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun                                                                                        $verifySchema$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun                                                                                        $verifySchema$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:183)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.verifySc                                                                                        hema(CSVFileFormat.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.prepareW                                                                                        rite(CSVFileFormat.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation                                                                                        Command$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$4.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:                                                                                        121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation                                                                                        Command$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$4.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:                                                                                        121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.driver                                                                                        SideSetup(WriterContainer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation                                                                                        Command$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation                                                                                        Command$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation                                                                                        Command$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLEx                                                                                        ecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation                                                                                        Command.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffect                                                                                        Result$lzycompute(commands.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffect                                                                                        Result(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(                                                                                        commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Spa                                                                                        rkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Spa                                                                                        rkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.appl                                                                                        y(SparkPlan.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.s                                                                                        cala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala                                                                                        :133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryE                                                                                        xecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.sc                                                                                        ala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSourc                                                                                        e.scala:487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:551)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                                        java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                                                                        sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I believe the DataFrame `l2` has column/s containing a complex type, please can you post the output of `l2.show()`

Comment: +---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[[1,1,4.076836144...|
|  2|[[2,6,4.933567648...|
|  3|[[3,7,19.06817406...|
+---+--------------------+

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error while writing dataframe with probablities to CSV . You may want to try below, which worked for me.

```
l2.toPandas().to_csv('l2.csv')
```